# nginx server block configuration for simultaneous reverse proxy and serving php files

Tags: nginx

I have configuration for icecast2 server that is reverse proxied through nginx because icecast does not support ssl fully.
i want to be able to reverse proxy icecast served files and at the same time run php from another location inside same domain name. For example proxiedicecast.org shows icecast served files and in proxiedicecast.org/status i can serve other content. 
I have default server block configuration that works for icecast but when i try to access php files from "proxiedicecast.org/status" browsers just download php files instead executing them.

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name proxiedicecast.org;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    location / {
        if ($ssl_protocol = "") {
          rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
        }
    }
    # php
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

#### SSL ######################################################

server {
    #ssl on;

    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/proxiedicecast.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/proxiedicecast.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot

    # Recommended security settings from https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security  /Server_Side_TLS
    # ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
    # ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:5m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
    resolver_timeout 5s;
    # Enable this if you want HSTS (recommended)
    # With or without preload (without very secure but not recommended)
    #  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubdomains;"
    #  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubdomains; preload;"
    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

    root /var/www/html;

    server_name proxiedicecast.org;
    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }


    location ~ /status {
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location / {
        #access_log /var/log/icecast/access_https.log icecast_combined;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

     # php
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use this `location` block for your status page:

```
location /status {
    rewrite ^ /status/index.php last;
}
```

That is, if your status `index.php` is located at `/var/www/html/status/index.php`.

There is no need to use regex modifier for `location` block here, since you don't to match `*/status*/`, a simple prefix match for anything starting with `/status` is enough.

Then, inside the `location` block, we rewrite the request to `index.php`, and nginx will start the location matching with the rewritten URI. This  will now be passed to `location ~ \.php$`, since there isn't another conflicting regular expression match for the same request.

For more information on how nginx processes `location` directives, look at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

Comment: When i test that it says 'invalid number of arguments in "try_files" directive'

Comment: I forgot that I nginx wants always two arguments for `try_files`. My edited answer now makes nginx return 404 not found if there is no `index.php`.

Comment: it still works as my original version. php files just get downloaded they are not passed to fastcgi

Comment: Please try my updated version with the `rewrite` directive.